# What feature must be installed to show the ASP icon in IIS?

Tags: iis-7, iis

An IIS 7, Windows 2008 R2 server is missing the ASP icon from the workspace pane when a web application is selected in the tree pane. What feature must I add to get the icon to appear?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "classic ASP" to IIS by following [Microsoft's documentation](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis).